# Convert numpy.float64 to integer

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Im currently working on an assignment but have encountered a problem. How do I convert a numpy.float64 to integer.

```py
import numpy as np

bike = np.loadtxt('Bike.txt')

def count_days(year, month, day):
    year_2011=[31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
    year_2012=[31,29,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]

    if (year == 2011):
        days= sum(year_2011[:(month-1)])+day
    else:
        days= 365+sum(year_2012[:month-1])+day
    return days

bike_2011 = bike[count_days(2011, 0, 0)-1]
bike_2012 = bike[count_days(2012, 0, 0)-1]
int(bike_2011)
int(bike_2012)

for e in len(bike_2012):
    if bike[e] > 8000 : print (bike [e], x)
```

This returns the following error.

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-f111e601c474> in <module>
      1 bike_2012.astype(int)
----> 2 for e in len(bike_2012):
      3     if bike[e] > 8000 : print (bike [e], x)

TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()
```

Comment: `bike_2012.astype(int)`, looks like you just discard the result, `astype` doesn't convert in place. Also, the code you've provided isn't the same as the code in your error message (`int` vs `bike_2012.astype(int)`)

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `bike = np.loadtxt('Bike.txt')` with `bike = np.loadtxt('Bike.txt').astype(int)` should do the trick. And while you're at it, you should delete `int(bike_2011)` and `int(bike_2012)` -- these do absolutely nothing.

On the other hand, you program has more severe problems, `count_days` returns a single number, so `bike_2011` and `bike_2012` are a plain variables, not lists or tuples, so trying to do `len(bike_2011)` will give you the same error, no matter if `bike_2011` is integer or float. You cannot take a length of a float (or integer).